# android - how to use/set up nested spinners?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-spinner

Working in fragments, I'm trying to return a value determined from selecting an item in a spinner and I can't make it work. The Toast notification inside the method isn't even working, it seems like the problem is within the method. How can I fix this?

```
public Spinner districtSpinner, countySpinner;
public int selectedDistrict;
```

are the variables used. Here's my parent spinner method, districtSpinner()

```
public void districtSpinner() {

    ArrayAdapter<String> Dadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.districtNames));
    Dadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    districtSpinner.setAdapter(Dadapter);

    districtSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                                                  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                             int position, long id) {
                                                      selectedDistrictPosition = districtSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                                                      switch (selectedDistrictPosition) {
                                                          case 0: {
                                                              selectedDistrict = 1;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 1: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=2;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 2: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=3;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 3: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=4;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 4: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=5;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 5: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=6;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 6: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=8;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 7: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=9;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 8: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=10;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 9: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=11;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          case 10: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=12;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                          default: {
                                                              selectedDistrict=1;
                                                              break;
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }

                                                  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                  }
                                              }
    );

}
```

this is the child spinner "countySpinner" that I am trying to make dependent on the parent spinner. The method should switch based on the selectedDistrict and set up the spinner with the corresponding string array containing each district's set of counties (R.array.districtx). Currently the second spinner does nothing, and as far as I'm concerned the countySpinner() isn't even called upon.

```
public void countySpinner() {

    switch (selectedDistrict) {
        case 0: {
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district1));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district2));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district3));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district4));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district5));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 6: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district6));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 7: {

            break;
        }
        case 8: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district8));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 9: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district9));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 10: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district10));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 11: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district11));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        case 12: {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district12));
            Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

            countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                   int position, long id) {
                                                        }

                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                                        }
                                                    }
            );
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How is districtSpinner() being used? It appears that you call it and expect the selected int to be the return.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek it's pretty much just being used to specify which district is selected. I'm trying to use the returned int in a switch case.

Comment: That is the problem. The `switch case` will only run when the item becomes selected and not when you call the `districtSpinner()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have stated the problem better like `I want to setup my second spinner according to the choice made in first spinner`. Then you better do like this as you have way to much equal code in it.

```
public void districtSpinner() {

ArrayAdapter<String> Dadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.districtNames));
Dadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
districtSpinner.setAdapter(Dadapter);

districtSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        int selectedDistrict = position+1;
        // do yourself a favor and intoduce an empty choice for 7;


        countySpinner(selectedDistrict);                                       
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  }
 }
);
}

private int getDistrictResourceId ( int districtnr ) {
   int resId = R.array.district1;
   switch ( districtnr )
   {
   case 1:
   resId = R.array.district1;
   break;
   case 2:
   resId = R.array.district2;
   break;

   // please add the rest
   }

return resId;
}

public void countySpinner( int districtnr) {

int resId = getDistrictResourceId( districtnr );

ArrayAdapter<String> Cadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(resId));
        Cadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        countySpinner.setAdapter(Cadapter);

        countySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          }
}
        );           
    }
 }
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks! I didn't even think of changing the resId how you did, that's a lot simpler than the approach I was using.

Answer (score 0):

You should see a Toast as far as i can see. But it does not make sense to let it return a value. You are only setting an adapter in that function. Indeed there is an onclicklistener and in on click selectedDistrict is set. But that only happens when the user clicks an item. Your function has long returned by then. Your function now returns with the static selectedDistrict value which it had before you called it.

Comment: How can I get it to store that value upon selection and then keep the value?

Comment: That depends a bit on how long you want to live with this value. But if it should survive an app restart you could use shared preferences.

Comment: I only really need it to survive long enough for the user to export the value along with the rest of the measurements/data logged at the end of a data logging session.

Comment: Not knowing the setup of your app you still could use shared preferences.

Comment: I updated the OP with the code from my second/child spinner. Hopefully it'll be a little clearer to see what I'm trying to do. I'm sure I'm doing this in a very inefficient/wrong way, since I've never dealt with nested spinners before.