# Android nested spinners

Tags: android, nested, spinner

I would like to implement nested spinners. I have looked all over the internet but didn't find anything. The idea is that each spinner item is a spinner. Is this even possible?

Comment: It means multiple spinner in your activity??

Comment: I would not recommend trying. Find another solution. For example an expandable listview where you can select an item

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936619/android-how-to-use-set-up-nested-spinners/25979446#25979446